# Java charAt error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, string, linked-list, char, copy-constructor

I have been having a problem writing the constructors for a Linked List project, and can't seem to figure out why charAt is not working in this context. I receive an error: cannot find symbol at the call for charAt.

```
   //copy
    public Project123(Project123 s){
        this.head = null;
        for (int i = s.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
            head = new charNode (s.charAt(i), head);
            }
        }
   //constructor
    public Project123(String s){
        this.head = null;
        for (int i = s.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
            head = new charNode (s.charAt(i), head);
            }
        }
```

I seem to not have the same problem as the other related posts.  It is lowercase and also seems to be correctly called.  If more context is needed I will post more.

Comment: *Please* don't name your class `Object`.

Comment: It actually isn't in the project.  I will change for sanity sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
  public Project123(Project123 s){
    this.head = null;
    for (int i = s.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
        head = new charNode (s.charAt(i), head);
        }
    }
```

`s.charAt(i)`

Here s is not a String, and so you can't use String methods on it -- won't work.

Instead in that copy constructor, iterate through the nodes copying nodes. Up to you if you're going to do deep or shallow copies.

Comment: Okay I see.  Could I then do something like head = new charNode (s.getChar(), head); ?

Comment: @user2210274: try it and see.

Comment: I have a getChar() method returning letter in the charNode class file.    It gives an error: cannot find symbol.  Shouldn't this work as Project123 is a charNode in this context?

Comment: @user2210274: Project123 extends charNode? It probably shouldn't do this, I'm thinking.

Comment: No I do not believe so.  To my understanding the constructor turns the string passed in into a series of charNodes i.e. "test" into [t]->[e] etc.

Comment: I would assume that calling getCharacter which returns the letter while iterating through the linked list would work.

Comment: @user2210274: If I were you, I would assume nothing until the code works. As for me, I cannot make specific recommendations about code and classes not shown.

Comment: I did figure it out due to your help!

Answer (score 0):

The first "s" in `s.charAt(i)` is not a String, it's a Project123.  The second one should be okay.  Just change:

```
public Project123(Project123 s){
```

to

```
public Project123(String s){
```

Comment: Then it wouldn't be a copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your two *methods* are actually constructors.  In the first, `s` is declared as an `Project123`, not a `String`.  So, it doesn't have a `charAt` method.  In fact, your (newly changed) copy constructor needs different techniques to clone it.  Take each node in the list, clone it, and use the clones.  I don't mean to use `Cloneable`.

Oh, and change `charNode` to `CharNode`, and change `Project123` to `CharLinkedList` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

A Project123 is not a String, so it won't have String methods.

But you've repeated yourself, which is poor coding anyway, so I would chain my constructors:

```
public Project123(Project123 p) {
    this(p.node.str); // not sure what you've called fields
}
```

Assuming here that `node` is the name of the field that holds the value.